# How do I find all the edges that don't lie on any of the shortest path?

Tags: algorithm, shortest-path

So, this question came in the last month's APAC. 
https://code.google.com/codejam/contest/4284486/dashboard#s=p2

The question is as follows:

Problem

Company G has a main campus with N offices (numbered from 0 to N - 1) and M bidirectional roads (numbered from 0 to M - 1). The ith road connects a pair of offices (Ui, Vi), and it takes Ci minutes to travel on it (in either direction).

A path between two offices X and Y is a series of one or more roads that starts at X and ends at Y. The time taken to travel a path is the sum of the times needed to travel each of the roads that make up the path. (It's guaranteed that there is at least one path connecting any two offices.)

Company G specializes in efficient transport solutions, but the CEO has just realized that, embarrassingly enough, its own road network may be suboptimal! She wants to know which roads in the campus are inefficient. A road is inefficient if and only if it is not included in any shortest paths between any offices.

Given the graph of offices and roads, can you help the CEO find all of the inefficient roads?

Input

The first line of the input gives the number of test cases, T. T test cases follow. Each case begins with one line with two integers N and M, indicating the number of offices and roads. This is followed by M lines containing three integers each: Ui, Vi and Ci, indicating the ith road is between office Ui and office Vi, and it takes Ci minutes to travel on it.

Output

For each test case, output one line containing "Case #x:", where x is the test case number (starting from 1). Then output the road numbers of all of the inefficient roads, in increasing order, each on its own line. (Note that road 0 refers to the first road listed in a test case, road 1 refers to the second road, etc.)

Now, I am trying to apply Djisktra's algorithm to this problem but I am not really able to think how can I do that?

So, djikstra's basically goes like, finding the minimum distance in the array everytime, but how can I apply it exactly? A pseudo-code is all I need. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Doing a shortest path search for each couple of nodes with Dijkstra's shortest path algorithm, assuming a [image] implementation, would add a [image] factor since you'll have to do it for each pair of nodes in the graph (furthermore it might prove not to be a terribly-easy-to-code algorithm with a mutable heap).

A straightforward solution would be the [all pairs shortest path with Floyd-Warshall](http://marcodiiga.github.io/all-pairs-shortest-path-transitive-closure/) and then check for each distance if that is the shortest one found.

The idea is the following: suppose you have this graph

[image]

Floyd-Warshall via a dynamic programming implementation (check the link I posted for the complete code) operates by recursively considering each node `K` as an intermediate node in a path connecting two nodes `X` and `Y`, i.e.

```
for each node K
  for each pair of nodes X and Y
    if the distance X -> K + K -> Y is less than the distance X -> Y
      X -> K -> Y is a better path than X -> Y, update the distance X -> Y
```

Be aware that this is a slow [image] solution though and better algorithms for all pairs shortest path are available.

Source: [all pairs shortest path with Floyd-Warshall](http://marcodiiga.github.io/all-pairs-shortest-path-transitive-closure/)

Comment: To be more precise, Floyd-Warshall considers, at step `k`, nodes from the set `{1, 2, ..., k}` as intermediate nodes.

Comment: @Marco A. I didn't exactly get the part where it will find the edges which are not a part of shortest paths. I know about Floyd-Warshall, but how will it lead to finding those edges?

Comment: @rohansingh Let's try again: by using floyd-warshall you will find all the shortest paths for every pair of nodes. If you then iterate over your original edges and check if you found a shorter path with Floyd-Warshall, you can then determine whether that path is optimal or suboptimal (in the latter case you found your *bad* path)

Comment: @MarcoA. so for example, I ran Floyd-Warshall and the first edge I came across was 2-3. So, I will be checking the value of distance from Floyd and also, the weight associated with that edge. If that weight comes out to be lesser, it's a suboptimal one otherwise it's not?

Comment: @rohansingh correct, but make sure to run Floyd-Warshall for every node (i.e. let the algorithm finish) in order to make sure you found the shortest path to compare with the original one.